# Unable to compile java source after update to IC 2016 using JDK 1.9

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, compiler-errors

I recently update from 15 to newer **IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 162.1812.2**. I have cleared all settings from previous version (don't import anything). JAVA SDK is **1.9.0 ea** and it works with IC14 and IC15 version without problem.
But it fails to compile any java code with:
**JAVA Error : Invalid flag release.**

Comment: Which jdk 9 version are you using? You could try to use the newest one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check here for a bug report of this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161326

It is fixed in EAP to be found here:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.3+EAP

In general it is a good idea to check Intellij bug database first for such product related issues:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA